# Not having any filter automatically in document Qlikview

Tags: filter, reset, qlikview

I have a document QLikview and I want when I launch it not having any filter , clear automatically without click on any button.
Is it possible ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

- Settings --> Document properties --> Triggers --> if "OnOpen (Has Action(s))" ---> select OnOpen --> press Edit Actions button on the right --> review the actions that are triggered when the document is open. If "Clear All" is present you can delete it if you want to change this behaviour.
- if there are no triggers in the document properties check the macro module ( Ctrl + M) and review the vbscript ( if available ). Part of this script should clear the selections.
- another option is selections to be cleared on activating the specific sheet but i highly doubt that this is your case